# Edit Control Watermark

Tags: c++, winapi, watermark, editcontrol

I would like to implement a grey text watermark in an edit control in C++ with Win32 API, but I'm not sure of any ways to do it besides handling WM_KEYDOWN messages.

I would like something like this:

[image]

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you talking about the gray text or the icon?

Comment: @Anders I'm talking about the grey text.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Send the [EM_SETCUEBANNER](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb761639(VS.85).aspx) message to your edit control.

Pass a unicode string to display in `lparam`.

e.g.:

```
SendMessage(hwnd, EM_SETCUEBANNER, (WPARAM) FALSE, (LPARAM) strW);
```